# The UV is bending in weird ways in the viewport when 3D View is in Rendered mode. How do I fix it?

Tags: uv, blender-internal-render-engine

The textures start look weird from certain angles.

I'm not sure if it happens in the renders themselves though.

[Here are the images.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvUTg.jpg)

Comment: So, why not try to render?

Comment: Screenshot of mesh in Edit mode and unwrap could lit some light on what happens there.